# Combining 2 sql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I wanted to ask can any one help me to join this two statement into one

```
SELECT * FROM worker_leave WHERE YEAR(yearAppplied) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM worker_leave WHERE YEAR(yearAppplied) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

I want to achieve counting the total leave a person have within current year and previous year total must not be more than 24 (Can be control at php side)

Comment: combine them how? the two where clauses are incompatible. a single value in a single field cannot be two different values at the same time.

Comment: what about using union all

Comment: Thanks union is the answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM worker_leave  
WHERE YEAR(yearAppplied) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
   OR YEAR(yearAppplied) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

This will give you combined results for both queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
SELECT * FROM worker_leave WHERE YEAR(yearAppplied) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM worker_leave WHERE YEAR(yearAppplied) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Make sure the columns returned by both queries are indentical [in structure]